# Spring BadCredentials Event not firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to log if a user tries to authenticate with wrong credentials. Therefore i have added this event listener class to my project:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener
        implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent>{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        System.out.println("test");
        logger.info("test2");
    }
}
```

Problem is it does not work at all. I use Spring Security default login page. The page shows "bad credentials" error when using wrong credentials, but my method above does not get called.
I have very similar code for a success event listener, which works wonderfully:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener implements
        ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired private UserService users;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        User user = users.get(event.getAuthentication().getName());
        boolean isAdmin = user.getRole().equals(User.ROLE_ADMIN);
        logger.info((isAdmin ? "Admin" : "User") + " with id " + user.getIdLink()
                + " has successfully logged in!");
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring Security Java Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

I have no clue whats going on here, help appreciated a lot!

Spring version: 4.0.9
Spring Security version: 3.2.5 (also tried 4.0.1)

---

Edit:

Okay, i set log level to DEBUG for Spring, but nothing. I searched for every occurance of "Listener" and the log states that instances of AuthenticationFailureListener as well as AuthenticationSuccessListeners have been created without any error.

I even put the log into diff tool (after replacing all times & censoring) and compared with a code version where FailureListener code is commented out, but didn't find something. You can search it yourself if you want to:
https://www.diffchecker.com/cwdn4sp4
On the bottom of the page you will find the plain log text on the left side.

---

Edit2: **Partly Solved**

Serges solution helped, here is my complete implementation of the onAuthenticationFailure method:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        Authentication auth =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(
                new AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent(auth, exception));
    }
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
}
```

Comment: Do you have proper component scan set up so that your `AuthenticationFailureListener` gets created as a bean? Enable Spring debug logging to verify that it is actually created. That will give you/us some more info to work with.

Comment: The FailureListener is in the same package as the SuccessListener, so scan should work with both. Ill try debug logging now, thx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is *by design*.

Javadoc for `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is clear on that :

*Event Publication :*

*If authentication is successful, an InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent will be published via the application context. **No events will be published if authentication was unsuccessful**, because this would generally be recorded via an AuthenticationManager-specific application event.*

(emphasize mine)

If you want to send explicitely an event for authentication failures, you could use a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` that would send the event and call base class `onAuthenticationFailure` method.

```
public class EventSendingAuthenticationFailureHandler
        extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler,
        implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    protected ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    @Override
    void onAuthenticationFailure(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                       javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,
                       AuthenticationException exception)
                         throws IOException,
                                javax.servlet.ServletException {
        // use eventPublisher to publish the event according to exception
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

You should be able to configure it that way :

```
@Bean
AuthenticationFailureHandler eventAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new EventSendingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}

@Autowired
AuthenticationFailureHandler eventAuthenticationFailureHandler;

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().failureHandler(eventAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: There is still a problem:`.formLogin().failureHandler(handler)` breaks the generated login page redirect on bad credentials (even if i call `super("/login?error")` in my handlers contructor). It leads to `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/GMM/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'GMM'` and a 404 page gets returned when using wrong credentials.

Comment: I think it is just a problem of configuration of the handler. What is the URL of your login page ? What happens if your type that URL directly in your browser (`http://host/context/xxx`), and same with `?error` at the end ?

Comment: My login page URL is currently http://localhost:8080/GMM/login Typing directly doesn't change any behaviour. /login?error returns a 404 in all cases.

Comment: Okay, i could not resolve the problem, but could evade it by using a custom login page.

Comment: In my case, I was overriding `protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` to customize my `AuthenticationManager` which broke the sending of this event. I needed to add `auth. authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher())` where `authenticationEventPublisher()` is an `@Bean` that returns a new `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher()`.

Answer (score 13):

I got this working in a different way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    // Inject applicationEventPublisher
    @Inject
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            // configure a auth event publisher
            .authenticationEventPublisher(new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher))
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

With these changes, my event listener was able to receive auth failure events.
This is with spring-security 4.0.2.RELEASE and spring-boot 1.2.5.RELEASE

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please post the whole example?

Answer (score 0):

The [LoggerListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/LoggerListener.html) works fine with Spring Security 3.2.8. See [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.2.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/LoggerListener.java/) for source code.

Your adpoted code:

```
@Named
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    private UserService users;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {

        if (event instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) {

            User user = users.get(event.getAuthentication().getName());
            boolean isAdmin = user.getRole().equals(User.ROLE_ADMIN);
            logger.info((isAdmin ? "Admin" : "User") + " with id " + user.getIdLink() + " has successfully logged in!");
        }
    }
}
```