# Cannot apply Spring Security to a Java project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, brute-force

I am trying to apply [Prevent Brute Force Authentication Attempts with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts#overview) to my Java project where I also use Spring Boot. However, there is a part using `web.xml`, but there is not a `web.xml` in my project. So, is it possible to apply that approach to a Spring Boot project that has not `web.xml`?

I also trying to add its maven dependency but it seems to be there is not. So, how can I apply that? Or is there a similar approach you can suggest for a Java + Spring Boot project? I look at Baeldung, but there is not. Any idea?

**Update:** On the other hand, I implemented all the classes except from `web.xml` and I think maybe there is no need to use `web.xml` as I already pass the login request to my service normally.

However, my service is not detect the failed login attempts. Should I call some method from `userRepository.findByUsername()` method does not find a user? Any idea?

Note: There is also a GitHub of the article on https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/tree/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/security.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final TokenService tokenService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;
    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    @LogExecution
    @Transactional
    public UserTokenDTO login(final LoginRequest request)
            throws JsonProcessingException, JOSEException {

        String ip = getClientIP();
        if (loginAttemptService.isBlocked(ip)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("blocked");
        }

        final User user = userRepository.findByUsername(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow(InvalidCredentialsException::new);

        
        final var userDTO = userService.findByUuid(user.getUuid());
        final var tokenDTO = tokenService.generateTokens(userDTO, true);
        return new UserTokenDTO(userDTO, tokenDTO);
    }

    private String getClientIP() {
        String xfHeader = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (xfHeader == null){
            return request.getRemoteAddr();
        }
        return xfHeader.split(",")[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by : "I also trying to add its maven dependency but it seems to be there is not." ? 
What do you use to configure your project ?

Comment: I use maven, and thought as if I could add web.xml as dependency.So, could you please have a look at that article and let me know about the usage of that approach?

Comment: Do I need to add `spring-security-web` and `spring-security-config` to my `pomi.xml` to get or use `web.xml`?

Comment: Maven wont add that `web.xml` . If you don't it it's because your are configuring your application using only Java. You must avec some `InitializerClass` check this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config

Comment: Thanks for this helpful page. On the other hand there is no web.xml is seen on the project of the article in my question. https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/tree/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung So, how can I convert or use that web.xml mentioned on the article? Any idea?

Comment: im pretty sure you dont need a `web.xml` and you can ignore what is written in the tutorial have you tried it without? When you write that it still doesn't work, we need more details about what is not working.

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried and now the only problem is that I cannot fire `AuthenticationFailureListener` and `AuthenticationSuccessEventListener` when username or passwords is not matched on my login service. I look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278293/spring-badcredentials-event-not-firing) page, but could not apply it for the example that I follow on [this](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/security/CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.java) page. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot comment(not enough reputation), but in the link below is explained why you cannot catch the `AutenticationFailureListener`, you have to use a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler(As Pilpo said).

[Spring BadCredentials Event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278293/spring-badcredentials-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have web.xml, you have to create a class like this in your spring configuration package

```
@WebListener
public class YourContextListener extends RequestContextListener {
    [...]
}
```

You might also add `@Configuration` annotation if Spring doesn't detect it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I have a Controller but I think I will also add this file you mentioned. What is the purpose of this file?

Comment: Do I need to add `spring-security-web` and `spring-security-config` to my `pomi.xml` to get or use `web.xml`?

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: Well, according to the javadoc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html, it allows request or session scoped bean in a JSF application. If you don't know what that is, maybe you don't need the file nor the web.xml. My guess, is that it allows Spring to retrieve information about the request with HttpServletRequest. But I don't think it necessary. On my project I do have HttpServletRequest witout web.xml or listener. Have you tried without it? If so, what error do you get or is it working?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have just tried as you mentioned and maybe I do not need `web.xml` as I already pass the request to my service. But I have another problem. Could you please have a look at my **Update** ?

Comment: What do you mean by failed login attempts? IP Blocked or inexisting user in DB? Either way, did you try putting two breakpoints at the start/end of your login method? Does your app go through them or not?

Comment: My login method catches the issue that user is not found. At this point, I think I should trigger the `loginAttemptService.loginFailed()` method. But I think it should be automatically triggered in such situation. Or, should I call that method?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think you have to call it. I think you should go through AuthenticationFailureListener (https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/security/AuthenticationFailureListener.java) when the login is KO and the exception is thrown. If it does'nt work, maybe its not used by your app. In such case, you either look for a way to use it or you just call your method as you want to do.

Comment: When login is failed, `InvalidCredentialsException` is thrown, but I cannot catch it in `AuthenticationFailureListener`. So, is there anything special that I need to implement or define e.g. a config so that I can catch this exception in `onApplicationEvent` of `InvalidCredentialsException` class?

Comment: Hmm in https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/SecSecurityConfig.java the listener doesn't seems to be registered, it's more the `authenticationFailureHandler` in `.failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)` that is used https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/security/CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.java Can you confirm?