# Cannot catch Exception in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, event-handling

I implement a brute force prevent mechanism as for my Login service as shown below by inspiring Baeldung's **[Prevent Brute Force Authentication Attempts with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts#overview)** page:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    public UserTokenDTO login(final LoginRequest request) {        

        if(!user.isValid) {
            throw new InvalidCredentialsException();
        }
        // code omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

When a user is not validated, `LoginService` throws `InvalidCredentialsException()` and then I am trying to catch this exception in `AuthenticationFailureListener` class:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener implements 
    ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
        final String xfHeader = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (xfHeader == null) {
            loginAttemptService.loginFailed(request.getRemoteAddr());
        } else {
            loginAttemptService.loginFailed(xfHeader.split(",")[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

When there is an error, then `loginAttemptService.loginFailed()` method will be called. However, I cannot catch the exception in my `onApplicationEvent()`. I have tried using different event types, but for some event e.g. `ApplicationEvent` it is triggered on each event and I should fire it only when the user is not authenticated when `InvalidCredentialsException` is thrown.

After making a search, I have seen that I need to make a config so that Spring Security catch these event on failure or success. But the definitions is not clear and I thought that maybe I can catch the event by using the correct event type in my `AuthenticationFailureListener` class. I also have an event Handler class, but I am not sure if it helps anything.

**Update:** Here is my `SecurityConfig`.  I still cannot fire `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent` and cannot get any exception `onApplicationEvent`.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    AuthenticationFailureHandler eventAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    private final AuthenticationFailureHandler eventAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().failureHandler(eventAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anybody else have experience about exception handling or Spring Security?

Comment: Your `AuthenticationFailureListener` won't catch an exception. You should emit an event using the `ApplicationContext` if you want it to catch the event. The `AuthenticationManager` normally does it for you if you are using it to authenticate the user. Take a look at the `ProviderManager` source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have no exğerience. Could you please post this as an answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279493):

> If authentication is successful, an InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent will be published via the application context. **No events will be published if authentication was unsuccessful**, because this would generally be recorded via an AuthenticationManager-specific application event.

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo. Actually I had read that thread and implemented similar approach. **BUT** I could not understand the **"... You should be able to configure it that way"** part. So, could you please clarify me about where I should define it? BTW I have a Spring Boot app.

Comment: @Henry usually you put `.failureHandler(eventAuthenticationFailureHandler)` in your AuthenticationFilter bean. I dont know where exactly you have to put it, depends on how you have configured your spring security context. If you can post it , I will help you figure out. 


Remember that your `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, must be a bean, you can do that, by adding `@Component` to your Handler or using `@Bean`  into your configuration class

Comment: Actually there is not a Apring Security config in my project and this brute force preventing part is the first part of Spring Security in my project. So, assuming that there is no config, could you pls give me an example and explain what I should add or implement to the project?

Comment: All dependes on your needs, the Spring Security Configuration its a pretty big topic to talk about. In this play list you will find some practical examples. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPd-u8ibXBY&list=PLVApX3evDwJ1d0lKKHssPQvzv2Ao3e__Q
Take a look at spring security reference too https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#introduction

Comment: the most basic configuration is this one, https://github.com/dangeabunea/RomanianCoderExamples/blob/master/SpringBootSecurity/HttpBasic/src/main/java/rc/bootsecurity/security/SecurityConfiguration.java, you can find the explaination in one of those videos in the playlist i linked to you (should be the number eleven). In the case you are gonna use tha configuration the failureHandler goes after the httpBasic() just like this ` .httpBasic().failureHandler(eventAuth....);`

Comment: I tried this but caused errors. On the other hand, my security config and I think my security config is more basic. I added it to Update. Could you pls have a look at **Update** in my question?

Comment: The errors are related to preventing request, for this reason there is no need to spend time on that. So, could you please have a look at my security config implementation and other implementations?

Comment: You may also post an example by using the article on Baeldung (that I followed) by updating some parts and omitting unncessary codes in it. Also adding a security config like mine. On the other hand, you can test it by simply adding a login method and throwing error (you do not need to implement authentication, etc)

Comment: Here you go, the full example https://github.com/xTheDoctah/AuthenticationFailureListener/tree/With_Failure_Handler @Henry. Just call http://localhost:8081/ and type some username and password (totally random) then you will se in your log HEADER NULL, it's printed by `AuthenticationFailureListener`

If you see Header Null printed twice just follow this example instead https://github.com/xTheDoctah/AuthenticationFailureListener (The only difference is that this one, doesn't implement any FailureHandler)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235886/discussion-between-a-caldarigi-and-henry).